# Get two array on different variable using json from servlet in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, arrays, json, servlets

**Servlet**

```
 String getCodeList = (new JSONArray(rmsCodeList)).toString();
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getWriter().write(getCodeList);
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var getdata;
$.post("GetItemCode", function(data) {
    getdata=data;

});
});
```

working fine, I get the complete array on  **getdata**

**Write Two**

```
 String getCodeList = (new JSONArray(rmsCodeList)).toString();
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getWriter().write(getCodeList);


 String getNameList = (new JSONArray(rmsNameList)).toString();
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.getWriter().write(getNameList);
```

How can I get two array on different variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var getdata1;
var getdata2;
$.post("GetItemCode", function(data) {
    getdata1=?;
    getdata2=?;

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the two arrays in a `JSONObject` and retrieve it in Javascript

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(
    new JSONObject()
        .put("codeList", new JSONArray(rmsCodeList))
        .put("nameList", new JSONArray(rmsNameList)).toString()
);
```

Then in Javascript you retrieve it as a property of the returned object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getdata1;
    var getdata2;
    $.post("GetItemCode", function(data) {
        getdata1 = data.codeList;
        getdata2 = data.nameList;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Send a JSON object containing two array values and set each one to the desired JavaScript variable.

Although you're writing the code like you're making a synchronous call, which will likely lead to problems.

Comment: Create a new `JSONObject`. `put` the two arrays into it. Use whatever names you `put` them as to extract them in your success callback. At least *try* to show some effort in understanding the APIs you're using.